# what are the numbers shown by od -c -N 16 <filename.png>

Tags: linux, binaryfiles, file-type, octal

I'm using linux and when I typed
  `od -c -N 16 <filename.png>`
I got `0000000 211 P N G \r \n 032 \n \0 \0 \0 \r I H D R 0000020`.
I thought this command tells me the type of the file but I'm curious about what the number 0000000 and 211 means. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`od` means "octal dump" (analogous to the hexdumper `hd`). It dumps bytes of a file in octal notation.

211 octal is 2 * 8<sup>2</sup> + 1 * 8<sup>1</sup> + 1 = 137, so you have a byte of value 137 there.

The `0000000` at the beginning of the line and the `0000020` at the beginning of the next are positions in the file, also in octal. If you remove `-N 16` from the call, you'll see a column of monotonously ascending octal numbers on the left side of the octal dump; their purpose is to make it instantly visible which part of a dump you're currently reading.

The parameter

```
-N 16
```

means to read only the first 16 bytes of `filename.png`, and

```
-c
```

is a format option that tells `od`

- to print printable characters as characters themselves rather than the octal code, and
- to print unprintable characters that have a backslash escape sequence (such as `\r` or `\n`) as that escape sequence rather than an octal number.

It is the reason that not all bytes are dumped in octal.

If you want to know the file type of a file, use the `file` utility:

```
file filename.png
```

Side note: You may be interested in the `man` command, which shows the manual page of (among other things) command line tools. In this particular case,

```
man od
```

could have been enlightening.